# Can the Kawasaki T-4 carry weapons?

Tags: trainer, ordnance

The [Kawasaki T-4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kawasaki_T-4) is a jet trainer aircraft. However, it seems to have two hardpoints.

> Armament
>
> Two hardpoints for external fuel tanks

Can these be used to carry weapons? E.g., unguided bombs or unguided missiles?

I suppose guided missiles require avionics for a more sophisticated fire-control system, fire-control radar, and similar — which I suppose the T-4 definitely does not have. However, please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Not much of an answer, but from what I've seen in my line of work, militaries will explore such options, hacking (both hardware and avionics) wherever they can even if they had bought the platform from a foreign OEM. None of these info will ever become public, if their security and intelligence agencies are any good. If you can think of it, they would have considered it as well. Viability is a completely different story though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Kawasaki T-4 actually has [three hardpoints that can carry weapons](http://www.military-today.com/aircraft/kawasaki_t4.htm)
: one underfuselage and two wingpoints (also confirmed [here](https://www.forecastinternational.com/archive/disp_pdf.cfm?DACH_RECNO=254)). The possible armament includes gun pods, long-range anti-ship missiles, air-to-air missiles, free-fall or retarded bombs and pods with 70 mm unguided rockets. Hence no way it could be said it cannot be armed.

This aircraft seems more for training but can be used in light attacks.

Comment: Seems like someone should revise the Wikipedia article! Good answer.